# Puppeteer times out when launching browser in Firebase Cloud Function - How to troubleshoot?

Tags: reactjs, node.js, express, google-cloud-functions, puppeteer

I'm trying to generate a PDF using Puppeteer within a Firebase Cloud Function. However, every time I attempt to launch the browser using Puppeteer, the function seems to hang and eventually times out. The original HTML content was quite large so I thought it might be that, so I have changed the content to a simple Hello World, didn't make any difference.

This makes me think there is a problem launching Puppeteer.

I've added multiple console logs to trace the execution, and based on the logs, the function successfully receives the request, processes the HTML content, and then starts the Puppeteer browser launch process.

But it never progresses beyond the "Launching browser using Puppeteer" step.

[Google Cloud Function Logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fBCBt.png)

I also get this CORS error, I can't seem to fix that:

[CORS error, Timeout Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5UNys.png)

Here is my cloud function:

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const cors = require("cors");
const chrome = require("chrome-aws-lambda");

app.use(express.json());
app.use("/fonts", express.static("fonts"));

// Set CORS headers
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "https://REDACTED.co.uk");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,PUT,POST,DELETE");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type");
  next();
});

// Use the cors middleware
app.use(cors({
  origin: "*", // Allow requests only from this domain
}));

app.post("/", async (req, res) => {
  console.log("Received request for generating PDF");

  const {htmlContent} = req.body;

  if (!htmlContent) {
    console.error("No htmlContent provided in the request body");
    return res.status(400).send("Missing htmlContent");
  }

  console.log("HTML content received:", htmlContent);

  console.log("About to launch Puppeteer");

  try {
    console.log("Launching browser using Puppeteer");
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
      headless: "new",
      // headless: false,
      args: ["--no-sandbox", "--disable-setuid-sandbox"],
      defaultViewport: chrome.defaultViewport,
      executablePath: await chrome.executablePath,
      ignoreHTTPSErrors: true,
    });

    console.log("Browser launched. Opening new page");
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    console.log("Setting content to the page");
    await page.setContent(`
      <style>
          @font-face {
              font-family: 'Inter';
              src: url('/fonts/Inter-Regular.ttf') format('truetype');
              font-weight: normal;
              font-style: normal;
          }
      </style>
      <div style="margin: 50px; font-family: 'Inter', sans-serif;">
          ${htmlContent}
      </div>
  `);

    console.log("Generating PDF from the content");
    const pdf = await page.pdf({
      format: "A4",
      printBackground: false,
      scale: 0.75,
      displayHeaderFooter: true,
      headerTemplate: "<div style=\"width: 100%; height: 50px;\"></div>",
      footerTemplate: "<div style=\"width: 100%; height: 50px;\"></div>",
      margin: {
        top: 70,
        bottom: 70,
        left: 50,
        right: 50,
      },
    });

    console.log("Closing the browser");
    await browser.close();

    console.log("Sending PDF response");
    res.set(
        {"Content-Type": "application/pdf", "Content-Length": pdf.length},
    );
    res.send(pdf);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error generating PDF:", error);
    res.status(500).send("Failed to generate PDF.");
  }
});

exports.generatePdf = functions.runWith(
    {memory: "2GB", timeoutSeconds: 500}).https.onRequest(app);
```

And the frontend from my React JS App:

```
try {
      console.log("Starting PDF generation process");
      console.log("Sending request with HTML content to the server");
  
      const response = await axios.post('https://us-central1-REDACTED-c40e9.cloudfunctions.net/generatePdf', {
          // htmlContent: detailsToUse
          htmlContent: "<h1>HELLO WORLD</H1>"
      }, {
          responseType: 'blob'
      });
  
      console.log("Received response from server. Processing blob data...");
      const blob = new Blob([response.data], { type: 'application/pdf' });
  
      console.log("Creating download link for the PDF");
      const link = document.createElement('a');
      link.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      link.download = 'DentalTreatments.pdf';
  
      console.log("Initiating download...");
      link.click();
  
      console.log("Download initiated. Cleaning up object URLs");
      URL.revokeObjectURL(link.href);
      console.log("PDF generation and download process completed");
  
  } catch (error) {
      if (error.response) {
          console.error("Error Status:", error.response.status);
          console.error("Error Data:", error.response.data);
          console.error("Error Headers:", error.response.headers);
  
          // Specific check for auth error
          if (error.response.status === 401) {
              console.error("Authentication error. The provided token may be invalid or expired.");
          }
      } else if (error.request) {
          console.error("No response was received:", error.request);
      } else {
          console.error("Error setting up the request:", error.message);
      }
  
      console.error("Detailed error:", error.config);
  }
```

I hope you can help please! Thank you

Comment: Please see [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors). Those logs and error could be provided as text, which makes the post more easily discoverable to people with the same error.

Comment: ok thank you, noted for future, have a good week ahead!

Comment: Thanks for the response. You can still [edit] the current post.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I got it, changed:

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");
```

to

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer-core");
```